# ¿Por qué no puedo abrir el emulador de Android? VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

actualmente tengo un problema para abril el emulador de Android. En VS 2015, cuando abro "VS-->Tools-->Android-->Android Emulator Manager" para crear el emulador no me ejecuta nada, trato de abrir la consola de errores para ver si me muestra algo pero no me muestra nada tampoco.

Acá un ejemplo de lo que hago:

1. Abro VS 2015, y ejecuto el Emulador de Android, no hace nada.

[image: Cuando intente ejecutarlo la primera vez]

2. Luego fui de nuevo a la misma ubicación para abrir de nuevo el emulador y me aparecen todas las herramientas deshabilitadas.

[image: Cuando intente ejecutarlo la segunda vez]

En la consola de errores no muestra nada:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has ejecutado como administrador?

Comment: Si claro, pero no me funciona.

Comment: En Herramientas - Opciones - Xamarin - Android Settings tienes todo en verde? Si es asi tienes que abrir el Android SDK Manager y asegurarte que en algunas de las versiones de android tienes bajada alguna System Image

Comment: La opción del menú "Android Emulator Manager" es una aplicación a parte, no está por defecto en Visual Studio. ¿La tienes instalada?

Si no la tienes instalada, consulta: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-emulator/xamarin-emulator-manager/

Comment: Por cierto, a mi ese emulador me da bastantes problemas. El que mejor funciona, al menos a mi (en mi caso, Visual Studio 2017), es el "Android Emulator for Visual Studio". Se instala desde Visual Studio Installer, y se ejecuta independientemente del Visual Studio.